# How can I make Python argparse to have dependency

Tags: python, argparse

I need one group of mutually exclusive parameters is required or not dependents on the value of a parameter, e.g.

I have three parameters -a -b -c

-b, -c are mutually exclusive group

## The following commands are some examples ok and not ok:

1. python test.py   # ok, no parameter is assigned

## when -a is assigned a value, -b or -c need to be enabled:

2. python test.py -a 100 -b  # ok
3. python test.py -a 100 -c  # ok
4. python test.py -a 100  # not ok, b or c is not enabled
5. python test.py -a 100 - b -c  # not ok, b and c are both enabled

## when -a is not assigned a value, -b and -c can't be enabled. Thus the following cases are not ok.

6. python test.py -b
7. python test.py -c
8. python test.py -b -c

Does argparse support this kinds of functions?

If so, how could I achieve it? Thanks!

Comment: If you're willing to make `-a` a subcommand rather than an option, you could use a [subparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Comment: testing after parsing is the simplest method.  This has been discussed a many other `argparse` questions.  `argparse` itself only has the flat mutually exclusive test.