# Should we use options to get information that is not optional but we do that to make it look more intuitive?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I am trying to write a python program that will provide some github features in cli like creating issues, creating repos, creating PRs, etc.

I came up with something like 
`github create issue --title <title> --description <description> --user <user> --repo <repo>`

I used argparse for this purpose

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.parser()
parser.add_argument('create', 
                    options=['issue', 'repo', 'pull')
                    action='store')
parser.add_argument('--title', action="store", type=str)
parser.add_argument('--description', action="store", type=str)
parser.add_argument('--user', action="store")
parser.add_argument('--repo')

parser.parse_args('create issue --title title --description desc --user user --repo repo')
```

I used the options `--title` and `--descriptions` to get the information in keyword form.

While options are meant to be optional, but according to my style of parsing:

- If `create` is `issue` then `--title`, `--description`, `--user`, `--repo` are required.

What will be the right approach of parsing the command `github create issue --title title --description desc --user user --repo repo` ?

Answer (score 0):

First a couple of tweaks:

```
parser.add_argument('--title', action="store", type=str)
```

can be simplified to

```
parser.add_argument('--title')
```

since this action and type are the defaults.  You do this with `--repo`.

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

reads from the commandline and puts the values in the `args` namespace.

```
args = parser.parse_args(['issue --title title --description desc --user user --repo repo'].split())
```

can be used to test this parser with a simulated list of strings.

Note that I dropped `create`.

```
parser.add_argument('create', choices=['issue', 'repo', 'pull'))
```

defines a `positional` that will be put in `args` as `args.create`.  The strings it accepts are the `choices` (not `options`).  An alternative is to use `--create`; in which case it behaves like the other arguments, only with a limit in accepted values.

If you want to require some arguments for a specific value, you need to do the testing after parsing, e.g.

```
if args.create in ['issue']:
    if args.title is None or args.user is None:
       parser.error('title and user required with issue')
```

This is almost a duplicate of a recent [How can I make Python argparse to have dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528184/how-can-i-make-python-argparse-to-have-dependency) which was also closed as a duplicate.

An alternative is to use `subparsers`.  But you can read about those in the docs and previous [argparse] questions.

Try these ideas and come back with a new question.

You'll have to write a custom `usage` and/or `help` paragraphs to describe the constrains to your users.